# How do I draw a transparent PNG in WPF on a canvas using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, png, transparent

This doesn't seem to be answered. I have a png ("Blue Arrow.png") which has a white background. I want to draw it on a canvas at location X,Y with rotation R with the white background being transparent.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? The Googles they're not turning up anything.

Comment: What you're asking about is called a color key. Traditionally, you'd use magenta (0,255,255) but any color will do. Unfortunately WPF does not have built-in support, but you can probably find an implementation of a color key bitmap somewhere. The easier solution is to just modify your .png file to use the alpha channel for transparency. GIMP is a free program that can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way in WPF to remove the background of a PNG and make it transparent. It would be much easier to start with a PNG that has a transparent background.

Even if you find an external library that will do color keying/replacement, the quality won't be as good as starting with a proper PNG.

Comment: Thanks. Found an online program to set the transparent color. Where can I find code to place the bitmap at a specific X,Y location on the canvas?

Comment: If you're wanting to do it through code, check out this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635892/how-to-set-x-y-coordinates-of-wpf-canvas-children-through-code

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: How do you specify the X,Y location that the image will be drawn at on the canvas? I can't find any way to set the drawing location coordinates.